# Python Pandas Merge result does not contain values from right dataframe

Tags: python, merge, pandas

I use python 2.7 and pandas 0.13
I try to merge two dataframes:

```
dfa[['descriptor_ref','issue_ref']]
dfi[['descriptor', 'cfit']]

dfm = pd.merge(dfa, dfi, left_on='descriptor_ref', right_on='descriptor', how='outer')
```

Both descriptor_ref and desriptor are dtypes: object.
The columns from the right dataframe (dfi) are present in the result (fdm) but the values are not. All columns from dfi are empty in dfm. The number of rows in dfm is equal to the number of rows in dfa.
What could cause this ?

Comment: can you post some data that reproduces this problem, also your python and pandas version, thanks

Comment: Could you also explain what you mean by lookup values, are you saying that dfi just has a descriptor column that matches the descriptor_ref column and you want to add some other description column to dfa?